# Issue in file operations in C++

Tags: c++, output

This is part of a c++ code that writes value of a vector of strings into a file.

```
int main () {

    //freopen ("out.txt", "w+", stdout);
    ofstream data;
    data.open("data.txt");  

    BinaryTree<string>* bt = new BinaryTree<string>;
    LoadBinaryTree(bt);
    fillArrayOfNodes(bt);

    for (int i = 0; drawArray[i] != "\0"; i++)
        data << drawArray[i] << endl;

    data.close();
    delete bt;
    return 0;
}
```

First, I couldn't write into the file. I mean after running the program and checking the output file, it was empty. after that, I noticed that my output format wasn't right. I changed it and now I can write into the file. (the code shown above is the modified code)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You are getting an error? Your file is not changing? Something else?

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is not a sufficiently accurate bug report.

Comment: @sashkello I get no errors! it runs but the file is not changing! (remains empty)

Comment: Show us what `drawArray` looks like.

Comment: array's contents are like this:

 d -> g
 d -> h
 h -> k
 b -> d
 a -> b
 a -> c
 e -> i
 c -> e
 c -> f
 f -> j
whenever I cout the array, it prints thing like above.
it's a string array
@0x499602D2

Comment: @user3227786 Okay I've got it. Hold on a sec while I make an answer.

Comment: What is `drawArray`? What does `BinaryTree` have anything to do with anything?

Comment: drawArray is a string array which is filled with a string. it doesn't matter what is binary tree, the array is filled with some strings that whenever I print it (using cout) its contest are printed correctly, just the way I want, like this: a -> b  b -> c  c -> a
the problem is that I cant fill the data.txt file with the content of this array @rubenvb

Comment: @Rasoolll the fact that is doesn't matter, matters. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're attempting to iterate through the array. The Standard C++ string class `std::string` should not be handled like a regular char array. That is, you shouldn't base your condition upon finding the null character. The correct way would be to iterate until you reach the length of the string.

Moreover, you should be using a vector of strings and inserting strings using `push_back()`:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

// fill vector with push_back()

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    data << v[i] << endl;
```

Comment: I got an error! (error C2228: left of '.size' must have class/struct/union)
it's an array like this:
string drawArray[100];
@0x499602D2

Comment: @Rasoolll This is important information that you should have told us about when you wrote the answer. Anyway, try my update.

Comment: @Rasoolll You have to use a vector of strings.

Comment: sorry about that, you know, I'm new here!
your update works! the code compiled and ran good, but that's not writing to file yet! (but yout works correctly with cout)

Comment: let me try vector, I'll be back in a minute. thanks

Comment: vector is not workin' too!! I think I should send my whole code for you

Comment: @Rasoolll You said it works with `std::cout`? That means there something wrong with your file stream. Check to see if the file is in an invalid state using `if (data) cout << "Good"` before the `for` loop. If you don't see that message, let me know.

Comment: yeah the problem is with my file stream because std::cout is working well! I tried a sample just like you said and that's not working! :(

Comment: @Rasoolll Replace `if (data)` with `if (data.is_open())`. Does it print `"Good"`?

Comment: @Rasoolll That's great! But what's actually working? What did you do to get it to work?

Comment: the replacing thing! I don't know what was wrong with that but now it's working just the way I want!
It means after running the code I got the text file I want (like thing that it std::cout gave me before)

Comment: Hey @0x499602D2 could you please vote up my poor question so I can be unblocked and can ask better questions now. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me! thank you very much buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the right headers like `<fstream>`.

Try this example: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: I've included that before

Comment: @Rasoolll That was not clear from your question.

Comment: Could you please vote up my poor question so I can be unblocked and can ask better questions now. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me! thank you very much buddy. :)

Comment: @Rasoolll Can you edit your question and improvie it? If you improve the question in all point criticized by other and me, I'll cancel my downvote.

Comment: I improved that and wrote the right issue I was facing with. Then I wrote the reason for that. Now it's modified I think. thanks :)